Must the fixed point of a function g commuting with a contraction be unique?
Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. Suppose $f: X\to X$ is a contraction and $g: X\to X$ is a function commuting with $f$, i.e.,
$$
  f(g(x)) = g(f(x)),\quad \forall x\in X.
$$
Clearly, $g$ has at least one fixed point in $X$ since for $f(x_0)=x_0$, $f(g(x_0))=g(f(x_0))=g(x_0)$ implies $g(x_0)=x_0$, by the uniqueness of the fixed point of $f$.
Must this fixed point of $g$ be unique?

Of course not. A counterexample is $f={\rm id}_X$.

@AnneBauval Since the OP mentioned “the uniqueness of the fixed point of $f$”, contractions here likely meant as in this Wikipedia article, namely Lipschitz functions with Lipschitz constants strictly smaller than $1$, in which case $\text{id}_X$ is not a contraction.

But if $g=\mathrm{id}_X$ the answer is still no.

@David The OP does not assume that $g$ is a contraction. Sorry, I just realize that my first comment had a typo. I meant $g={\rm id}_X$ (of course!).

There are also other counterexamples. Say, if $X$ is a real or complex Banach space, $f(x) = \alpha x$ for some $|\alpha| < 1$, then any linear $g: X \to X$ commutes with $f$. A linear $g$ can, of course, have plenty of fixed points.

@AnneBauval Ah, in that case, of course. I thought you meant $f = \text{id}_X$ and then an arbitrary $g$ with more than one fixed points.

@AnneBauval: this is an answer, please post it as such.

There are many counterexamples. The simplest one is $g={\rm id}_X$.
